# How does .first work on a CollectionProxy in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a couple models set up like this:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contract
end
```

I have a feature test set up like this...

```
feature "Some cool functionality", js: true do
  let(:contract) { create(:contract) }
  let(:invoice) { create(:invoice, contract: contract) }

  #etc...
end
```

While debugging the test I noticed this...

```
(byebug) p contract
#<Contract id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-25 01:52:52", updated_at: "2014-02-25 01:52:52">
(byebug) p invoice
#<Invoice id: 1, contract_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-25 01:52:52", updated_at: "2014-02-25 01:52:52">
```

**Here's the confusing part:**

```
(byebug) p contract.invoices.first
nil
```

I thought that would return my `invoice` defined in my feature test.

However, I think I can verify that `contract` has one `invoice`...

```
(byebug) p contract.invoices.count
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."contract_id" = $1  [["contract_id", 1]]
1
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Try reloading the contract from the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `contract.reload`

When you call `let` the value of the variable/method is cached after the first time it is invoked. So when you call `contract.invoices.first` you are invoking `invoices` on the cached `contract` object currently in memory.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure you're using the most up-to-date data, try using Rails' [`reload!` console method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html#method-i-reload-21):

```
# from command line
reload!
```